# Can a reductive group act non-linearly on a vector group?

Tags: algebraic-groups, characteristic-p, gr.group-theory, group-schemes

Let $k$ be a field; I'm going to discuss linear algebraic groups over $k$. The question I'll pose is only interesting when the characteristic is $p>0$.

*1. Some motivation*

A *vector group* is an algebraic group isomorphic (over $k$) to a product of (finitely many) copies of the additive group $\mathbf{G}_a$.  Let $U$ be any connected unipotent group over $k$. If $k$ is perfect, or if $U$ is $k$-split, then $U$ has a filtration 
$1 = U_0 \subset U_1 \subset \cdots \subset U_n = U$
where each $U_i$ is normal in $U$ and each $U_i/U_{i-1}$ is a vector group.  If $U$ is a normal subgroup of a linear group $G$, you can
arrange that each $U_i$ is invariant under conjugation by $G$.  This suggests that to study the *group extension* $$(*) \quad 1 \to U \to G \to G/U \to 1,$$ one might profitably study first the case where $U$ is a vector group.

Let $G$ be a linear group and suppose that the unipotent radical $R$
of $G$ is defined over $k$ and is $k$-split (each of these conditions
can fail in general; they always hold when $k$ is perfect). Then the
question of whether $(*)$ splits when $U=R$ is precisely the question
of whether $G$ has a *Levi factor*; cf. this [question of Jim Humphreys.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22118/are-there-reasonable-criteria-for-existence-non-existence-of-levi-factors-or-th)

*2. Action on a vector group*

Let $U$ be a vector group and suppose that the linear group $G$ acts
on $U$ by algebraic group automorphisms. 
The action of $G$ on $U$ determines an action of $G$ on
$\mathfrak{u}=\operatorname{Lie}(U)$.

> **Question (first approximation):** Is there a $G$-equivariant
>   isomorphism $\mathfrak{u} \to U$ (where the vector space
>   $\mathfrak{u}$ is viewed as a vector group in the obvious fashion)?

I'll say that the action of $G$ on $U$ is *linearizable* if
there is such an equivariant isomorphism.

Some remarks: If the action of $G$ on $U$ is linearizable, then $G$
centralizes the action of the multiplicative group $\mathbf{G}_m$ on
$U$ obtained by transport of structure from scalar multiplication on
$\mathfrak{u}$.  This $\mathbf{G}_m$-action determines a grading on
the algebra $k[U]$ of regular functions on $U$ which is stable
for the action of $G$ on $k[U]$.

*3. Partial answers*

*Postive:* If the characteristic of
$k$ is $0$, the above question has always an affirmative answer. (Use the exponential mapping $\mathfrak{u} \to U$; this is $G$ equivariant e.g. because there is a faithful linear representation of the semidirect product $G \ltimes U$).

*Negative:* If $G = \mathbf{G}_a$, the
question has a negative answer in char. $p>0$. Consider the action of
$G$ on $V = {\mathbf{G}_a}^2$ given by the rule $$x.(a,b) = (a +
xb^p,b).$$ 
The action of $G$ on $\operatorname{Lie}(V)$ is trivial, so there is no
$G$-equivariant isomorphism $\operatorname{Lie}(V) \to V$.

*4. What I meant to ask.*

> **Refined question:** If $G$ is reductive, is the action of $G$ on a vector group $U$
>   always linearizable?

An affirmative answer would mean that when $G/U$ is reductive, one can study the group extension $(*)$ using cohomology of linear representations of $G/U$.

Note that are known examples even in char. 0 (Schwarz, Kraft,...) of 
actions of reductive $G$ on
affine space $A=\mathbf{A}^n$ which are not linear, but, at least in
char. 0, these actions don't respect a vector group structure on $A$.

Answer (score 6):

[Update below:  I think this answers the question now.]  Let's suppose that we're working over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $p$.  Let $Fr$ denote the Frobenius automorphism.

From a recent paper of Tanaka and Kaneta (Hiroshima Math. J. 2008), I found that $Aut(G_a^n)$ (the automorphism group of the vector group $G_a^n$ over $k$) can be identified with:
$$\{ A \in M_n(k)[[F]]^\times : A,A^{-1} \in M_n(k)[F] \}.$$
Here, we work in a ring of noncommutative power series in the formal variable $F$, with coefficients in the matrix ring $M_n(k)$, subject to the natural relation:
$$F \cdot m = Fr(m) \cdot F.$$
I.e., one may pass all F's to the right, by applying Frobenius to the entries of the matrices.

Now, there is a natural surjective homomorphism $lin$ from $Aut(G_a^n)$ to $GL_n(k)$, obtained by taking the "constant term" of the power series.

What does the kernel of $lin$ look like?  Is it (representable by?) a pro-unipotent group scheme over $k$?  I have no idea.

**Update:**  Following David's comment, it appears that $Ker(lin)$ is a pro-unipotent group over $k$.

The image of a reductive group is reductive, even in the pro-affine setting (Section 3 of Mostow-Hochschild, Pro-Affine Algebraic Groups, Amer. J. of Math 1969.  Happily this result is right before the assumption of char=0).  Any reductive subgroup of a unipotent group is trivial, in this same reference.  Hence the image of a reductive group in $Ker(lin)$ must be trivial.

**Update:**  Let $\alpha: G \rightarrow Aut(G_a^n)$ be an algebraic action of $G$ on the vector group $G_a^n$.

It follows that $H = \alpha(G)$ is a reductive subgroup of the pro-affine group $Aut(G_a^n)$, which does not intersect the pro-unipotent subgroup $U = Ker(lin)$.  It remains to prove that $H$ is conjugate to the subgroup $GL_n \subset Aut(G_a^n)$.

Let $H' = lin(H)$ be the projection of $H$ in $GL_n$ -- this projection is an isomorphism from $H$ to $H'$.  We find that $H \cdot U = H' \cdot U$, and $U$ is the unipotent radical of $H \cdot U$.

Now the remaining question:  are Levi factors of $H \cdot U$ (geometrically, since we work over $k = \bar k$) conjugate?  To this, I think I defer back to the OP, who has recently written a paper on this topic, which will hopefully adapt to this pro-affine group setting.

Comment: Hi Marty! You can filter $Aut(G_a^n)$ with $G^j$ being the group of such power series which are the identity modulo $F^{j}$. Then $G^0/G^1$ is $GL_n(k)$, and $G^j/G^{j+1}$ is $G_a^{n^2}$ for higher $j$. If we were dealing with finite dimensionsal group schemes, that would show $G$ is unipotent. I don't know, though, what subtleties may exist in the pro-unipotent case.

Comment: @David:  How can you be sure that the successive quotients are $G_a^{n^2}$?  Is this written down somewhere?  To me, it seems clear that the quotients are closed subgroups of $G_a^{n^2}$ -- sufficient for the pro-unipotence result -- but not that the quotients are the "whole thing".

Comment: I have no idea whether it is written down, but isn't it clear? You just want to show that, for any $n \times n$ matrix $A$, the element $1-A F^j$ is a unit. It's inverse is $1+A F^j + A Fr^j(A) F^{2j} + A Fr^j(A) Fr^{2j}(A) F^{2j} + \cdots$.

Comment: The point that I got from Tanaka-Kaneta is that one must work with power series which are polynomials in $F$, and whose inverse is also polynomial in $F$.  That may imply some nilpotence condition on the coefficient matrices.

Comment: Actually - that sounds dumb.  I guess these are just invertible polynomials in the noncommutative polynomial ring.  I just copied from Tanaka-Kaneta without thinking.

Comment: Oh, I see. I hadn't noticed that you had single brackets in some places and double brackets in others. In that case, I agree that it isn't obvious. Fortunately, as you point out, we don't need to care about this point.

Comment: Hi Marty, this looks great. Somehow I believed that $\operatorname{Mat}_n(k[F])^\times$ was the automorphism group, but 
didn't know to expect anything about pro-unipotence of the kernel.
How is the "power series" condition on $A$ different from just requiring $A \in \operatorname{Mat}_n(k)[F]^\times = \operatorname{Mat}_n(k[F])^\times$? Or is that what your subsequent comment ("Actually - ...") speaks to?

Comment: That's what my "actually" comment speaks too.  I think you're correct and it's simpler to just write $A \in Mat_n(k[F])^\times$.  Glad this works out - I don't work with unipotent groups in $char = p$ very often.

Comment: Let $R$ be the kernel of $\operatorname{GL}_n(k[F]) \to \operatorname{GL}_n(k)$. Your argument presumably shows that there are no maps $G \to R$ for reductive $G$. I don't see the next step, though. One needs to see that the image of $G$ is conjugate to a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n(k) \subset \operatorname{GL}_n(k[F])$; why is that?

Comment: @George:  Uh oh.  You're right.  We might need a "conjugacy of Levi" theorem, in the pro-setting, to get this to work out.  From your recent work, I think you're the expert on this part!  I agree that it's problematic, and I'll edit my post accordingly. 

Comment: @Marty: Further comments... (1) My instincts say GL$_n(k[[F]])$ is pro-affine, but not GL$_n(k[F])$. Is this right? is it related to your exchange with Speyer yesterday? (2) The kernel of GL$_n(k[F]/F^2) \to $GL$_n(k)$ probably identifies with the Frobenius twist of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ as a module, so there may be non-vanishing $H^1$ and hence no conjugacy of Levis. (But despite my comment yesterday, it isn't clear that full conjugacy is req'd (just need image of $G$ centralized by "scalars").)

Comment: ...finally (3) I'm not sure I see why the image of $G$ should be in **any** complement to $R$ in GL$_n(k[F])$. It is possible to have
a semidirect product $H = L \cdot R$ with a unique conjugacy class of complements to $R$ and a subgroup $G < H$ which intersects $R$ trivially for which $G$ is not a subgroup of any conjugate of $L$ -- see e.g. the example in 3.3 of http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1007.2777


Comment: Well, those remarks sound negative, but I think you have made a good suggestion. My feeling before asking was that there was probably a counter-example that I somehow didn't know. Now you've made me optimistic that the answer to the "refined question" is yes.

Answer (score 4):

I somehow just realized that although I've now know the answer for a while, I had failed to give the answer to this question...

In fact, for (any) field of characteristic $p>0$, there are (plenty of) examples of reductive groups $G$ which act by group automorphisms on a vector group $U$ for which the action is *not* linear -- i.e. there is no $G$-equivariant isomorphism $\operatorname{Lie}(U) 
\simeq U$.

For an example, see [< my preprint @ gmcninch.math.tufts.edu >](http://gmcninch.math.tufts.edu/abstracts.html#Linearity) (especially section 5). Given a non-split
extension
$$(\flat) \quad 0 \to W \to E \to V \to 0$$
of finite dimensional $G$-modules, one can view the extension as being defined by a suitable sort of cocycle. One can then "twist" this cocycle by Frobenius,
yielding a vector group $\tilde E$ on which $G$ acts by group automorphisms.

As a $G$-module, the Lie algebra $\operatorname{Lie}(\tilde E)$ is isomorphic
to $V \oplus W^{(1)}$, where the exponent on $W$ denotes the first Frobenius twist.

By construction,
there is a $G$-equivariant surjection $\pi:\tilde E \to V$, and the kernel
of $\pi$ identifies with $W^{(1)}$. 
But there is no $G$-equivariant homomorphism of algebraic groups $V \to \tilde E$ which is a section
to $\pi$, hence there can be no $G$-equivariant isomorphism between $\tilde E$ and
$\operatorname{Lie}(\tilde E)$.

Since there are plenty of non-split extensions $(\flat)$, there are plenty 
of examples...

On a more positive note, let $V$ be a vector group on which $G$ acts.
The main result of the preprint just mentioned shows that if $G$ is connected,
if the unipotent radical of $G$ is defined over the ground field, and if 
$\operatorname{Lie}(V)$ is a simple $G$-module, then the action of $G$ on $V$ is linear.
In particular, it follows (for $G$ as above) that if $G$ acts on a split unipotent
group $U$, there is a filtration of $U$ by closed $G$-stable subgroups such that
the quotients are vector groups on which $G$ acts linearly.